# Add user ID to array in Comments model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following method in my comments_controller:

```
def plus
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:comment_id])
  @user = @comment.user

  @comment.increment!(:plus)
  @user.increment!(:plus)

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to post_path(@post) }
    format.js
  end
end
```

This just creates a "+1" for every comment. Now I'd like to also add the user ID to an array of user IDs stored in the comment attribute `plus_ids`. But I'm not sure how to create an attribute array.

What is the best way to do this? I'm looking for the equivalent of just updating the attribute:

```
@comment.update_attribute(:user_ids, 1)
```

Is there something like this perhaps?

```
@comment.update_array(:user_ids, current_user.id)
```

Comment: In comment model define `serialize :plus_ids, Array` and you should be able to use plus_ids as attribute

Comment: But how would I go about actually updating the array at that point? I assume it's something like `@comment.push(:plus_ids, current_user)` ?

Comment: `@comment.plus_ids << current_user.id` then `@comment.save`

Answer (score 0):

In comment model define

```
serialize :plus_ids, Array
```

This will allow `plus_ids` to act as `attribute array` then you should be able to use plus_ids as attribute.

To add elements to `plus_ids` array, In controller action.

By default `plus_ids` will be `nil` so

```
@comment.plus_ids ||= []
@comment.plus_ids << current_user.id 
@comment.save
```

Comment: This didn't work as intended. `:plus_ids` is updated, but with 0, not the `current_user.id`.

Comment: try inserting, numeric value directly. rather than `current_user.id`

Comment: Still 0. In console doing `Comment.last`:

`plus_ids: 0`

Comment: This shoud work, try defining `attr_accessible :plus_ids` in model, no need if you are using `rails 4`